# Quarkus removes unused annotations at compite/build time, which we need at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, quarkus

My project is based on Quarkus and the use of Reflections helps me to search for classes which implement specific annotation.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(path);
Set<Class<?>> customAnnotationClassSet = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(CustomAnnotation.class);
```

The resulting set is correct, it is filled with classes, but I cannot apply following method over the classes, the result will be null.

```
cls.getDeclaredAnnotations() --> null
```

Instead, when I use a specific class, I can access its declared annotations.

```
CustomClass.class.getDeclaredAnnotations() --> getting annotations
```

This problem occurs only when starting the app over jar file, otherwise it works.

It looks like Quarkus removes unused annotations at compite/build time, which we need at runtime.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: How is the annotation class declared?  Did you include this?  `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

Comment: What `Reflections` are you referring to? If `io.quarkus.arc.impl.Reflections` then that's a private API and you shouldn't be using that at all.

Anyway, scanning for annotations sounds like something that should be done at build-time, so maybe you should consider writing a Quarkus extension that inspects the Jandex index to locate classes with the annotation, and do whatever you need with them (during build time). If you need to pass this information to runtime for some reason, I'd perhaps go with a synthetic CDI bean that holds the information and can be injected in the application.

Comment: I assume you're using `org.reflections` and I've just tried that, and it worked for me as expected (I can get the declared annotation), so I'd guess that @StephenC is right and you just don't have a runtime retention on the annotation.

Comment: Yes, my annotation does include @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME). Sorry, I forgott to tell you, that it does NOT work when the app is startet over jar file, otherwise it works. I cannot get it running.